# Как автоматически резолвить конфликты в командной строке?

Tags: git, pycharm, jetbrains, git-merge

В PyCharm и прочих IDE от JetBrains есть кнопка "Resolve automatically" для автоматического решения конфликтов при мерже/ребейзе. Можно ли подобное сделать через командную строку для `git rebase`? Если это реализовано отдельно от ванильного гита, то можно как-то вынести функционал этой кнопки в командную строку?

Понятно, что кнопка работает не во всех случаях, но большего мне и не надо.

Comment: лайкать своё : `-s ours` или лайкать чужое : `--strategy theirs `

Comment: @AlexGlebe, это не всегда работает, иногда надо давать `-X theirs` или `-X ours`.